# Simple explanation needed for very basic question about gradient

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, vector-analysis

Suppose we have complex vectors $x$, $y$ and complex matrix $A$. Then, how to find the gradients of following functions

$$f_1(x)=x^Hy$$
$$f_2(x)=x^HAx$$ with respect to $x$. I can find them when all of them are real but I do not know how to find them when the matrices are complex. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When ${}^H$ denotes the conjugate transpose your functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not linear or quadratic functions of a complex vector variable, and in general are not real valued. You should add the meaning of "gradient" in such a situation.

Comment: In terms of Wirtinger derivatives
$\,\nabla f_1=0\;\,{\rm and}\;\nabla f_2 = A^Tx^*\;$